# Fragment created but not visible on itemClick of listView. Stuck here

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is my fragment activity code

```
public class Show extends Fragment {
private int local;
private String[] names = {"Alexndra Daddario", "Anne Hathaway", "Dakota Johnson",
        "Emma Stone", "Emma Watson", "Emmy Rosum", "Jessica Alba",
        "Kristen Stewart", "Marian Cotillard", "Natalie Portman"};
private int[] res = {R.drawable.alexandra_daddario, R.drawable.anne_hathaway, R.drawable.dakota_johnson, R.drawable.emma_stone, R.drawable.emma_watson, R.drawable.emmy_rosum, R.drawable.jessica_alba, R.drawable.kristen_stewart, R.drawable.marion_cotillard, R.drawable.natalie_portman};

public Show() {
    Log.d("dbg", "constructor of fragment");
    // Empty constructor required
}

public static Show newInstance(int position) {
    Bundle bndl = new Bundle();
    bndl.putInt("POSITION", position);
    Show show = new Show();

    show.setArguments(bndl);
    Log.d("dbg", "new instance just called");
    return show;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    Log.d("dbg", "onCreate of fragment called");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    local = getArguments().getInt("POSITION");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_show_layout, container, false );
    ImageView iv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.display);
    TextView tv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.abhinetri_ka_naam);

    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(res[local]);
    iv.setImageDrawable(d);
    tv.setText(names[local]);
    rootView.postInvalidate();
    Log.d("dbg", "onCreateView of fragment just called");
    return rootView;
}
```

}

And here is the code inside click listener of my Listview. This is where i am creating my fragment, by passing the position of item clicked, and that position is going to be the arguments of that fragment. Using position i am creating views. That's it but in my app nothing happens when i click an item.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Show show = Show.newInstance(position);

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(0, show).commit()

            Log.d("dbg", "Item clicked");
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Does the `onClick` get invoked? Do you see your Log message `Item clicked`?

Comment: Yes they are shown

Comment: The answer below has a good point, a first parameter of `add` is the id of the layout where the fragment will be added, it must not be null.

Comment: I don't understand. I am new to programming. There is one layout that defines fragment's layout with all the view in it, which will get inflated when called Fragment's on create view. But what is a container. Please i need some explanation.

Comment: A container is something where your fragment should live, you have your Activity, which probably has a `FrameLayout` or `fragment` tag in XML, which is a place for a fragment, instead of zero you should define something like `R.id.fragment_placeholder`, where `fragment_placeholder` is an id of your container that you defined in XML.

Comment: Ok now I understand. But what if i don't need fragment to be placed in specific part  of that activity screen but instead make it to take the whole screen

Comment: You can structure your app so that `Activity` will only contain a `FrameLayout` and then you can swap the fragments in, and they will be full screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem :) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(0, show).commit()

/**
     * Add a fragment to the activity state.  This fragment may optionally
     * also have its view (if {@link Fragment#onCreateView Fragment.onCreateView}
     * returns non-null) into a container view of the activity.
     * 
     * @param containerViewId Optional identifier of the container this fragment is
     * to be placed in.  If 0, it will not be placed in a container.
     * @param fragment The fragment to be added.  This fragment must not already
     * be added to the activity.
     * @param tag Optional tag name for the fragment, to later retrieve the
     * fragment with {@link FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag(String)
     * FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String)}.
     * 
     * @return Returns the same FragmentTransaction instance.
     */
    public abstract FragmentTransaction add(@IdRes int containerViewId, Fragment fragment,
            @Nullable String tag);
```

You are passing 0 as your containerViewId. So it's not placed in container. Pass your container view id there.